# How to see which NUnit test case failed in Teamcity build?

Tags: nunit, teamcity

In the build log I can see just a single line 
"Name of the dll" unit tests failed.

This dll has around 140 test cases. Which one failed. how to see that? or how to configure that so that it start coming in the build log?

Comment: how are you running the tests? Do you need to add a specific XML report to view the results? https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/XML+Report+Processing

Comment: We are running test cases using Nunit console. Any report that can show failed test cases (name of the test case which failed) will be enough.